# Hide/show button for the password field in the Woocommerce My Account page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password

How can I add a hide/show button for the password field in the Woocommerce My Account page?

A button or a eye icon

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be there.  If it's not, there's a chance the CSS has been mislaid similar [to this bug](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/31742)

Add this css to your stylesheet.

```
.woocommerce form .password-input, .woocommerce-page form .password-input {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
}
.woocommerce form .password-input input[type=password], .woocommerce-page form .password-input input[type=password] {
padding-right: 2.5rem;
}
.woocommerce form .show-password-input, .woocommerce-page form .show-password-input {
position: absolute;
right: 0.7em;
top: 0.7em;
cursor: pointer;
}
.woocommerce form .show-password-input::after, .woocommerce-page form .show-password-input::after {
font-family: dashicons;
speak: never;
font-weight: 400;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
margin-left: 0.618em;
content: "\f177";
text-decoration: none;
}
```